# Opening Rdata and getting each object to perform functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a couple of RData with different names within the same directory.
And within each *RData,
and within each Rdata there are,
for example, if I load a single RData,

```
load("results.CG_ID.RData", ex <- new.env())
    names(ex)
    "results"
```

and then,

```
names(ex$results$CG_ID)

[1] "table"           "coef"            "fitted"          "pvaluesMarginal"
[5] "null"            "algorithm"
```

From which I need to use `table` and `fitted` to perform function
I need to merge them based on the columns and filter the rows so on.
In the directory, I have 5 RData to complete the analysis.

Both `table` and `fitted` are dataframes.

I am not able to figure out how can I do it within a loop or inside a function. Any suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: `list.files` will tell you the file names. You can loop over them and read them in with `load`

Comment: Yeah looping over by for loops possible but then I need to merge the files based on the names of Rdata file that I cannot figure out in efficient way

Comment: Would be great can you show an example script, if you have one